# Redshift | Sub-categorizing Products Types Based On Product_IDs

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have the following table:

| order_id | product_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 5 | 2 |

And below the sizes of the product_id (this table is just to demonstrate the sizes so should not be used, we know by the `product_id` the size of the product):

| product_id | product_size |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Large |
| 2 | Large |
| 3 | Small |
| 4 | Small |
| 5 | No size |
| 6 | No size |

We are trying to create a label called `product_type` based on the products that are found within the `order_id`. Based on the product size (shown above) we want to categorize a bundle. A bundle can be labelled as:

- Product_id: 1,2 -> `Large Set`
- Product_id: 1,3 -> `Mixed Set`
- Product_id: 2,4 -> `Mixed Set`
- Product_id: 1,4 -> `Mixed Set`
- Product_id: 2,3 -> `Mixed Set`
- Product_id: 3,4 -> `Small Set`
- Product_id: 5,6 -> `Single` (these are individual products and do not matter)

*The order of how the product_id shows should not matter, as long as it's within the same order_id.*

So in turn, the 1st table should become this:

| order_id | product_id | product_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Large Set |
| 1 | 2 | Large Set |
| 1 | 5 | Single |
| 2 | 4 | Mixed Set |
| 2 | 2 | Mixed Set |
| 3 | 3 | Small Set |
| 3 | 4 | Small Set |
| 3 | 5 | Single |
| 3 | 6 | Single |
| 4 | 1 | Single |
| 4 | 6 | Single |
| 5 | 5 | Single |
| 5 | 2 | Single |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't covered all the combinations - what is an order that has a 1 and a 4?  What about a 2, 3, & 4?  If you can explain what you want in words we can get closer.  I'm thinking you want to create a pair of flags by order that indicate "contains large" and "contains small" and join that to the data and have a case statement that computes what you want the product_type to be but it isn't completely clear from the description provided.

Comment: Roughly how many distinct product IDs do you have? Similarly, roughly how many "product types" do you anticipate having in total?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, long weekend. For this example I have 6 DISTINCT product_ids. As you can see 1,2 are large and 3,4 are small. If both large products are found in an order, then just keep the product_type as large (same for small ones). However, I want to update the label when we have a combination of both a large and small product to mixed. So technically there are 4 distinct products types (large, small, mixed, no size). The no size products do not alter anything, so they can be "ignored".